# MongoDB Get the no of liked users count?

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("531d68dab0b80560100dd205"),
    "id": 47,
    "userId": "2",
    "content": "Like Check ",
    "datetime": "2014/03/10",
    "parent": null,
    "files": [
        ObjectId("531d68dab0b80560100dd203")
    ],
    "category": null,
    "comments": [

    ],
    "type": null,
    "likes": [
         "4",
        "4",
        "6",
        "12",
        "1"
    ],
    "recipients": [
        "4",
        "4",
        "6",
        "12",

    ]
}
```

I have a collection called posts, i need to find out the liked users count of a post from that collection. please help.
I have tried below codes in my MongoDB terminal.

```
db.posts.aggregate([{$unwind : "$likes"}, {$group: { _id:null, number :{$sum :1}}}])
```

but the result was this `{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }`

Comment: This is something best done client side in PHP itself like so: `count($doc->likes)`

Comment: Okay. Etiquette lesson. 1. If you have a question about someones **answer** then comment on that answer. 2. **Do  not** downvote just because you didn't get an expected result without asking questions. Your question was answered, **you** acted inappropriately. That was on the question you deleted before posting it again. Also **bad**. If you wan't to know how to **fix** your problem. Ask **another** question with those details. And give credit where credit is due when you learn something. That is the fair way to operate here.

Comment: Neil really sorry for that you have told earlier that the above post not the standard that's why i have deleted that post. really sorry

Comment: Fix your data or ask how in another question. As it stands the aggregate given by @Gh0stik will count your "strings" correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write like this:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {$project: {"likes" :1}},
  {$unwind : "$likes" },
  {$group: {"_id": "$_id", count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("531d68dab0b80560100dd205"),
            "count" : 5
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: sorry getting same error, db.posts.aggregate([   {$project: {"likes" :1}},   {$unwind : "$likes" },   {$group: {"_id": "$_id", count: {$sum: 1}}} ])
{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }

Comment: @Naveen It's a string not a number. Please listen.

Comment: Try reset our server and restore db from dump.

Comment: @Gh0stik. Sorry keep trying. That should work just fine.

Comment: You do these operations? 
1) Make a database dump. 2) Drop the entire database. 3) Restore the database.

Comment: i dont know how to do this in mongoDB, because i am new in mongoDB

Comment: @Neil Lunn. I know... :)

Comment: You got my vote anyway, for solving the problem. Bit of advice. Don't get dragged into fixing a problem you were not asked to solve in the first place http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222357/252977

Comment: If you are a beginner, I recommend you take the free course on Mongo: [Mongo Course](https://education.mongodb.com/courses/10gen/M101J/2014_March/about) 
I was held it when I studied Mongo.